# Progressbar not showing any color change

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have successfully changed the color of my progress bar to the colors available in Color (blue, green etc.), but when I give the hexcode of a particular color I get a bar with nothing in it. How can I resolve this?

```
ProgressBar pg = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBarDownload);
final float[] roundedCorners = new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
ShapeDrawable progressDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(roundedCorners, null,null));
progressDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0x01060012);//<-----problem here?
ClipDrawable progress = new ClipDrawable(progressDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
pg.setProgressDrawable(progress);   
pg.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal));
pg.setProgress(40);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this..

```
  ProgressBar pg = (ProgressBar)row.findViewById(R.id.progress);
    final float[] roundedCorners = new float[] { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 };
    pgDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(roundedCorners, null,null));
    String MyColor = "#FF00FF";
    pgDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(MyColor));
    ClipDrawable progress = new ClipDrawable(pgDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
    pg.setProgressDrawable(progress);   
    pg.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.progress_horizontal));
    pg.setProgress(45);
```

import this

import android.graphics.drawable.*;

[progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951978/change-progressbar-color-through-code-only-in-android)

Comment: ,I tried that, but my app crashed .it shows unknown color in logcat

Comment: choose diffent color in MyColor string

Comment: it doesnt work with color codes given in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#holo_blue_dark

Comment: @Abhilash do you want to do this programatically

Comment: @Abhilash check the above link progressbar

Comment: Do these color support in prior ICS Api ?I was trying to use holo_blue_light.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code its works for me

```
            String source = "<b><font color=#ff0000> Loading. Please wait..."
                    + "</font></b>";
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "",

            Html.fromHtml(source), true);
            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
```

Comment: Thanx for this tip but I dont want to use Html class in my code

Answer (score 1):

Try to use RGB values instead of hex color code, you can easily find the RGB values of the hex color code using ColorPic or any other similar tool.

Answer (score 0):

try like this"

```
Drawable progressDrawablePause = MainActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.download_progressbar_pause_bg);
            progressDrawablePause.setBounds(bar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds());
            bar.setProgressDrawable(progressDrawablePause);
            bar.setProgress(60);
```

first: set the drawable bounds
second: set the progressdrawable
third:setprogress