# Color accent (default color) not changing in lollipop and marshmallow

Tags: android, xml, progressdialog, android-6.0-marshmallow

How to change the default color in `Android 5.1` and 6.
How to Make Layout look like API 19 in API 22,23?

I have been using this color to show progress bar color:

```
 <color name="colorAccent">#EFAD04</color>
```

It's working in kitkat and lower versions but not in lollipop and Marshmallow

here's the progressBar.java

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progress_bar);

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP|| android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    {
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_Launch);

        progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(Progressbar.this, R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    }else {
     progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor( R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);

    handler = new Handler();
    Thread thread = new Thread(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        sleep(100);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();
        }
```

}

in API level 19 or less, progress bar is like:
[image]

And in Marshmallow Nexus 7, it's like:
[image]

I have changed the build versions also in activity.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951978/change-progressbar-color-through-code-only-in-android

Comment: @sasikumar Nope, its not helping, but thanks

Comment: @PiyushSoni Add more code like your `values/styles.xml` and `values-21/styles.xml`

Comment: values 21 xml is there, <resources>>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    </style>
</resources>
do i have to add for marshmallow too like values 23 or something?