# How to change color of circular ProgressDialog without set drawable or change color accent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to create a `ProgressDialog` with custom color but I want to keep the original format of the circular. I also don't want to change the color accent because it will also change other component color like `Switch`...

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom `drawable` for this. Replace `colorAccent` and other colors with your colors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="1440" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="15"
        android:useLevel="false" >

        <size
            android:height="75dip"
            android:width="75dip" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:centerColor="@color/colorAccentCenter"
            android:startColor="@color/colorAccentCenter"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

Comment: Hi, the above code works with me, but there are anyway to do this by Java code?

Comment: Let me have a look.
I suggest you to follow this example, as of now.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951978/change-progressbar-color-through-code-only-in-android

Comment: This solution use for `ProgressBar` not `ProgressDialog`

Comment: The link I've provided is for ProgressBar, not ProgressDialog.

Comment: My question about `ProgressDialog`

Answer (score 0):

you can write a style in style.xml under v21 folder like below:

`<style name="ProgressBar" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar">
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/red</item>
 </style>`

and use it like this

`ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = new  ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
myProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.ProgressBar)
myProgressDialog.show();`

Comment: And how about above v21?

Comment: when you put it in v21 folder it supports above APIs too.