# How to set progressBar color in android?

Tags: android

So far I am just seeing an option to set background. I want to set the filled portion to one color and the unfilled portion to another color.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change progressbar color through CODE ONLY in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951978/change-progressbar-color-through-code-only-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this, setting background of progressBar to color of unfilled portion and setting progressTint to filled portion color.